# Issue with sending packet

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, packet-sniffers

I define IP Header and Payload and I don't Know how can I add payload to packet and send packet to server.

I try this but I got error :

```
IPPACKETNAME() + PayLoad
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable to your situation without knowing more but here is a function to send a post request to a server. 
the requests.post can be changed to whatever type of request you need. e.g.

requests.get

requests.put

etc

```
import requests
def PostRequest(url,data1):
    r=requests.post("'"+url+"'",data=data1)
    return r.content
```

Usage:

```
response= PostRequest("http://192.168.1.7","DATA")
```

EDIT

This is some code to send a raw packet to a server.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 80)
#print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)



    # Send data
    message = input()
    message = str(message).encode()
    print('sending "%s"' % message)
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)


    data = sock.recv(16)
    amount_received += len(data)
    print('received "%s"' % data)


    print('closing socket')
    sock.close()
```